# Muti-row SELECT, where should I put the results? DataTable vs Class Model?

Tags: c#, oop, database-design, model

Currently, I am dumping the entire result set of the select in a data table using the following lines of code:

```
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQLCommand);
da.Fill(ds);
```

Then I read the data I need by iterating over the rows and then finding the values of each item using `row["ID"].ToString()` While this felt pretty easy to throw together, I worry about the minor overhead brought about by using a DataTable because I'm getting the feeling that they are far less efficient that mapping a class Model to each row using the DataAdapter.

Which is prefered - Using a datatable and processing each row in a foreach or having explicitly mapped class models with an enumerator to signify rows?

How would I go about mapping the data reader to an object?

If I were to try to get idea of the benefit of using one over the other, how would the benefit be quantified?

Comment: "How would I go about mapping the data reader to an object?" Ever heard of something called ORM? Look up Entity Framework, this is not the 90's

Comment: Easy, @CamiloTerevinto... Keep in mind that Stackoverflow is not populated just on experts. There are some novices here, too.

Comment: Hey Bitz, would [Cade Roux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1799186/3993154) in [Filling custom C# objects from data received stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799064/filling-custom-c-sharp-objects-from-data-received-stored-procedure) -  work in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better if you use a Class because it is strongly typed, however there is a better option that you must consider, it is Entity Framework which basically creates all the model for you and you no longer have to create your own classes and maintain them. here you can see a good guide to map your DB with EF
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I would usually opt for EF6, but in this case, the overhead of loading the entire library for what would be a single table, isn't inherently worth it. 

I would have to manually map each row to an object, which is why my main question is really "is it worth it"?
For a full codefirst app, for sure, but I'm not sure if it is in this case...